# Certification Problem After Upgrading OpenSSL 1.1.0 to 1.1.1 in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: openssl

recently I wanted to upgrade my OpenSSL from version 1.1.0 to 1.1.1. I did it using instructions given in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102803/how-to-upgrade-openssl-1-1-0-to-1-1-1-in-ubuntu-18-04). 
The solution [Kevin Bowen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1102803/how-to-upgrade-openssl-1-1-0-to-1-1-1-in-ubuntu-18-04) gave was perfect, except that now I'm having trouble using `wget` when accessing https sites. See this example:

```
$ wget https://www.rfc-editor.org/materials/tutorial76.pdf
--2019-03-23 19:39:07--  https://www.rfc-editor.org/materials/tutorial76.pdf
Resolving www.rfc-editor.org (www.rfc-editor.org)... 4.31.198.49,001:1900:3001:11::31
Connecting to www.rfc-editor.org (www.rfc-editor.org)|4.31.198.49|:443... 
connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.rfc-editor.org's certificate, issued by ‘CN=Starfield Secure Certificate Authority - G2,OU=http://certs.starfieldtech.com/repository/,O=Starfield Technologies\\, Inc.,L=Scottsdale,ST=Arizona,C=US’:
Self-signed certificate encountered.
To connect to www.rfc-editor.org insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

Note: I have also tries `sudo update-ca-certificates -f` to update the list of CAs I have locally.

Comment: do you experience this issue with common sites such as `https://www.google.com` , `https://www.youtube.com/`?

Comment: Yes. I do. I have tested many common sites.

Comment: Hi. I'm having the same issue. Were you be able to resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: No. I have also tried reinstalling all the certifications but it did not work.