# Broken pip3, pipenv and add-apt-repository on Kubuntu 18.10, probably something wrong with SSL lib

Tags: python3, ssl

I am on Kubuntu 18.10 with python 2.7.15 and 3.6.7 installed and output of `lsb_release -a` is

```
LSB Version:    core-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch:security-9.20170808ubuntu1-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:        18.10
Codename:       cosmic
```

`pip` works on my machine since its for python 2.7 and output of `pip -V` is

```
pip 9.0.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)
```

But typing pip3 gives segfault. The output is just `Segmentation fault`. Same output for pipenv. I have tried removing and installing python3-pip several times, deleted pip cache in `/home/<username>/.cache`. When i try to add any PPA using apt-add, i get this output

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 380, in get_ppa_info
    ret = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 110, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_lp(lp_url)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 104, in get_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_https(lp_url, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 96, in get_info_from_https
    data = func(lp_url=url, accept_json=accept_json, retry_delays=retry_delays)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 139, in _get_https_content_py3
    cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 210, in urlopen
    raise ValueError('SSL support not available')
ValueError: SSL support not available

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 136, in <module>
    shortcut = shortcut_handler(line)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 1020, in shortcut_handler
    ret = factory(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 469, in shortcut_handler
    return PPAShortcutHandler(shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 426, in __init__
    info = get_ppa_info(self.shortcut)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 392, in get_ppa_info
    _get_suggested_ppa_message(user, ppa))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 349, in _get_suggested_ppa_message
    lp_user = get_info_from_lp(LAUNCHPAD_USER_API % user)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 104, in get_info_from_lp
    return get_info_from_https(lp_url, True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 96, in get_info_from_https
    data = func(lp_url=url, accept_json=accept_json, retry_delays=retry_delays)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 139, in _get_https_content_py3
    cafile=LAUNCHPAD_PPA_CERT)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 210, in urlopen
    raise ValueError('SSL support not available')
ValueError: SSL support not available
```

Another symptom why i think there is an issue with ssl is that when i `import ssl` in python2 terminal, it works. But importing ssl in python 3.6 gives segfault

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ssl
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**UPDATE**

When i import any other module before `ssl`, say `hashlib`, i get a different error

```
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hashlib
>>> import ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 101, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

Comment: Can you try reinstalling the `libpython3.6-minimal` package? This is supposed to provide the `/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py` file that seems to break the interpreter.

Comment: @ByteCommander, Yes, like `sudo apt remove libpython3.6-minimal` and then `sudo apt install libpython3.6-minimal`? When i try removing it with `sudo apt remove libpython3.6-minimal`, it shows a large number of packages that will be removed like `apparmor`, `apport-kde`, lots of libboost libs. Can it make the system unusable?

Comment: Don't remove it, that would indeed uninstall many other important things. `sudo apt install --reinstall libpython3.6-minimal` reinstalls the package without changing any dependencies. Should have mentioned that directly, sorry.

Comment: @ByteCommander No apologies please :). I tried that. Still same issue.

Comment: Can you paste this exact command and show the output? `sudo dpkg -V | awk '$2!="c"{print $NF}' | xargs dpkg -S | grep -Ev 'diversion|, ' | grep -Po '.*(?=: )' | sort -u` What this does is to let `dpkg` scan all files that belong to any installed package on your system and compare them to the respective hash that is stored with the package. That way it can find any changed or corrupted files. The rest of the line processes the output to give you back a list of the packages they belong to instead of the changed files themselves.

Comment: @ByteCommander It prints 4 lines ---
code
libindy-crypto
openssl
python3-update-manager

Comment: That looks promising. I don't know what this `libindy-crypto` is (doesn't seem to be part of the standard repos), but if `openssl` was broken, that could definitely cause your problem, I think. Try reinstalling it with `sudo apt install --reinstall openssl` and maybe also the other mentioned packages.

Comment: `libindy-crypto` is non-system project and irrelevant here. I did `sudo apt install --reinstall` for openssl, code, python3-update-manager and finally libpython3.6-minimal. But still same issue.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas :(

Comment: @ByteCommander Thanks for the troubleshooting :)

Comment: @ByteCommander I noticed one more thing, updated by question (see the last section)

Answer (score 2):

Removing existing openssl from `/usr/bin/openssl` and  `/usr/local/bin/openssl` and reinstalling openssl using [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1102966/14148) fixed the issue. Before that i also tried the following as @ByteCommander suggested

```
sudo apt install --reinstall openssl
sudo apt install --reinstall code 
sudo apt install --reinstall python3-update-manager
```

Comment: Oh nice, you found a solution. `/usr/local/bin/openssl` looks like something that was manually installed outside the package manager (compiled from source maybe?). If both exist, the one in `/usr/local/bin` would take priority (PATH order), and if that is an incompatible or broken version, it can cause the issues in question. Good find :)

Comment: In my case, all of three `install --reinstall` and removing anything steps were not necessary; following https://askubuntu.com/a/1102966/14148 was quite enough for complete success.